# can't get my grid items to stretch parent div

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a website with css grid (first time).

Here is what I have so far:

[image: Here is what I have so far]

The problem is in the red area, I want the 3 elements in the button to span the entire height of the red area. This is my current css:

```
#red{
    background-color: red;
    padding-right: 5px;
    height: 100%
    grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 33% auto auto;
}

#upperelement{

    grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
    background-color: blue;
}

#upperelementselect{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    background-color: #404040;
    color: white;
}

#middleelement{
    padding-top: 5px;
    grid-area: 2/1/4/2;
}

#middleelementselect{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    background-color: #757575;
    color: white;
}

#lowerelement{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    grid-area: 1/3/2/4;
}

#lowerelementbutton{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    background-color: #404040;
    color: white;
}
```

And here is my html in short:

```
<div class="red">
<div id="upperelement"><select id="upperelementselect"></select></div>
<div id="middleelement"><select id="middleelementselect"></select></div>
<div id="lowerelement"><button id="lowerelementbutton"></button></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it would probably be a lot easier with a table, but that is not the point :)

Comment: A lot of the sintaxe for css grid related properties are wrong, and you provably should use fr units instead of percents. Take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, there's a selection of things wrong - or not ideal - here, and it's hard to offer a proper solution without the rest of the context. But you can achieve more or less what you asked about with something like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.controls-column {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.side-content {
  padding: 5px;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1/4;
}

.control {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

.select-top {
  background-color: #404040;
}

.select-middle {
  background-color: #757575;
}

.button {
  background-color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="controls-column">
    <select class="control select-top"></select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="controls-column">
    <select class="control select-middle"></select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="controls-column">
    <button class="control button">button</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="side-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto quibusdam obcaecati quod distinctio est reprehenderit, sint incidunt culpa unde nobis consequatur ut temporibus, molestiae facilis. Cum veritatis delectus necessitatibus maiores?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto quibusdam obcaecati quod distinctio est reprehenderit, sint incidunt culpa unde nobis consequatur ut temporibus, molestiae facilis. Cum veritatis delectus necessitatibus maiores?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto quibusdam obcaecati quod distinctio est reprehenderit, sint incidunt culpa unde nobis consequatur ut temporibus, molestiae facilis. Cum veritatis delectus necessitatibus maiores?
  </div>
</div>
```

Apart from that, you should definitely check out some guides like [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and/or some tutorials, because what you're missing is mostly some fundamental understandings about the CSS Grid Layout principles and sintaxe. Hope that helps getting you started.